# World building - Sky color, star class based on the color of the plants

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, stars, sun

Starting a new project here

If my plant foliage is blue-green/turquoise and my under water plant are in the reddish-brown/ochre color - What color should the sky be (mid day and dawn/dusk) and what would be the Star class ??

That should be also on a similar size planet orbiting a slightly bigger star than the sun. I would like the sun to have a pale blue coloration.

Any help or clue is welcome!!!

Comment: (1) There is no link between the color of foliage and the spectral composition of the light coming from the sun. (2) Color is a *sensation*. It exists in the mind, and only in the mind: it is not a physical quantity, it does not exist in nature. Therefore, when you say that leaves are *turqoise* you implicitly add *"for humans"*, because humans are the only species for which we can speak of color perception. Whatever colors, if any, the native inhabitants of the distant world may perceive, they will almost certainly be unlike what humans do. (3) Our own sun is pale yellow: and it's irrelevant.

Comment: And, of, welcome to Worldbuilding! We are happy to have you contribute to the site, and I hope that you will find it useful. Have you tried to search this site for similar questions? Such as [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/73210), or [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63259), or [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3371)? For some strange reason, many people believe that there is a linkage between the yellowness of our sun and the greenness of (most of) our land plants... (Spoiler alert: there isn't.)

Comment: Greetings!  Be sure to check out the [tour] and the [help] and learn [what Worldbuilding is all about!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about)  While you've got an interesting question here, it's pretty nearly a duplicate of at least half a dozen other queries in this forum. One common reason questions get downvoted is because querents fail to do even the most basic research, which includes using the search bar at the top of the page!

Comment: As others have said, star color has nothing to do with plant color. It almost has nothing to do with sky color (which is due to Rayleigh scattering in gasses, and all gasses scatter in the blue/violet spectrum). Search the site for "rayleigh scattering" and "sky color" to get a lot of info - you'll probably find ideas worth chasing.